# iText Out of memory on a 5440032-byte allocation

Tags: java, android, itext

I have encountered a problem when I am extracting text from PDF.

**01-29 09:44:15.397: E/dalvikvm-heap(8037): Out of memory on a 5440032-byte allocation.**

I looked up the contents of the page and it has a image above the text. What i want to know is how do I catch the error and skip that page? I have tried:

```
try {
        pages = new String[pdfPage];
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
        for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pdfPage; pageNum++) {
            // String original_content = "";
            // original_content = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,
            // pageNum, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            Log.e("MyActivity", "PageCatch: " + (pageNum + fromPage));
            strategy = parser.processContent(pageNum,
                    new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            readPDF(strategy.getResultantText(), pageNum - 1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The **try catch** above does not catch the error of **strategy = parser.processContent(pageNum,
                    new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());** 
I already tried commenting out all the lines inside the for loop and no error. but when i leave out **strategy = parser.processContent(pageNum,
                    new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());** and it errors.

Comment: How big is the PDF in question? Which PdfReader constructor do you use? Try the one using the random access file or array constructor.

Answer (score 0):

as i have understood about the error, that occurs when the memory is not enough to hold the data that you are reading, I believe you can't catch that error.

I would strongly suggest you to drop some old data, and make sure to just hold not too heavy data in your variable.

or refer to this

[Out of memory error due to large number of image thumbnails to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569960/out-of-memory-error-due-to-large-number-of-image-thumbnails-to-display)

Comment: What if I only want text but not the image? will it skip the image

Comment: yah, i think that will work because image especially with great resolution will consume lots of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You want to *catch the error and skip that page* and tried using

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

which didn't do the trick. Unless the DalvikVM handles out-of-memory situations completely different than Java VMs, this is no surprise: The `Throwable` used by Java in such situations is an `OutOfMemoryError`, i.e. not an `Exception` but an `Error`, the other big subtype of `Throwable`. Thus, you might want to try

```
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
```

or

```
} catch (Error e) {
```

or even

```
} catch (Throwable e) {
```

to handle your issue. Beware, though, when an `Error` is thrown, this generally means something bad is happening; catching and ignoring it, therefore, might result in a weird program state.

Obviously, though, if you (as you said) only want to try and skip a single page and otherwise continue, you'll have to position the `try { ... } catch() { ... }` differently, more specifically around the handling of the single page, i.e. inside the loop.

On the other hand, dropping all references to objects held by the PDF library and re-opening the PDF might help, remember Kevin's answer to your question [Search Text and Capacity of iText to read](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Search-Text-and-Capacity-of-iText-to-read-tp4657270p4657271.html) on the iText-Questions mailing list. Following that advice you'd have all iText use and a limited loop (for a confined number of pages) inside the `try { ... } catch() { ... }`, you'd merely remember the last page read in some outer variables.

Furthermore you can limit memory usage by using a `PdfReader` constructor taking a `RandomAccessFileOrArray` parameter --- readers constructed that way don't hold all the PDF in memory but instead only the cross reference table and some central objects. All else is read on demand.